# semaphores for client side storage?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, storage

I'm developing an instant message app with node.js and socket.io and am saving messages the  client receives in client side storage to load into their chatbox after they refresh the page. The issue is when they have multiple browser tabs open and are receiving messages for the same chatbox on all of those connections. Is there a clean way to lock the local storage if it's already updated with the latest value? The client side code is written javascript.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of several ways to assure only one instance of a message is stored locally, but the easiest is probably using some form of hash or checksum to guarantee message uniqueness.

So assuming you create an object to contain a single message like:

```
var msg={ timestamp:new Date, user:'joe', message:'text' };
```

Instead of storing messages in a array ordered by time like:

```
localstore.push(msg);
```

Store them in an object as:

```
localstore[createHash(msg)]=msg;
```

Where `createHash()` constructs a unique key from the contents of msg, like:

```
function createHash(obj){
  var result='';
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(k){
    if(obj.hasOwnProperty(k)){
      result+=obj[k].toString();
    }
  });
  return result;
}
```

And when you want to display the messages in the chat box, sort them by their timestamps like:

```
var msgs=[];

Object.keys(localstore).forEach(function(k){
  if(localstore.hasOwnProperty(k)){
     msgs.push(localstore[k]);
  }
});

msgs=msgs.sort(function(a,b){
  return a.timestamp.getTime() - b.timestamp.getTime();
});
```

While many (including me) will point out that this is neither efficient nor elegant, it's probably the easiest solution you'll find without using an external hashing library to guarantee uniqueness, like MD5.